# Mathematical expectation of the area of the quadrilateral

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

A point is randomly selected on each side of the unit square. Find the mathematical expectation of the area of the quadrilateral formed by these four points.

It is clear that we can assume that our square can be viewed with vertices at points $(0;0), (0; 1), (1; 1), (1; 0)$.

Then let $x_1, x_2$ be the abscissae of the points on the lower and upper sides of the square, respectively. $y_1, y_2$ are the ordinates of the points on the right and left sides of the square, respectively. Then the area of this quadrilateral can be calculated using this formula:

$$1 - \frac{1}{2}(x_1y_2 + (1-x_1)y_1 + (1-y_1)(1-x_2) + x_2(1-y_2)).$$

In general, it is now enough just to take the corresponding integral. But is it possible to use simpler reasoning to calculate the expectation in order to avoid integration by "four-dimensional square"

I will be grateful for any help!

Comment: It's a quadruple integral, but you are integrating a polynomial, with constant integration bounds. Seems feasible.

Comment: Of course, this is feasible, but I'm rather just wondering if there is a simpler solution?

Comment: The answer is obviously $1 - 2E(X_1Y_2),$ which is a slight simplification.

Answer (score 3):

The following only works if all points on a side have equal probability to be selected.

Say three points $F,G,H$ have been selected. Any point on the remaining side, $E$, can be reflected w.r.t. the midpoint of that side, $M$, to obtain another point $E'$. With simple triangle geometry you can show that the average area of $EFGH$ and $E'FGH$ is simply the area of $MFGH$.

Therefore, fixing the point in the middle does not change the expected area of quadrilateral. Now, simply fix all four points to be the midpoint of their respective side and calculate the area of the quadrilateral.

[image: Quadrilateral]

Comment: Yes, sure!  I did not notice a such approach to this problem. Thank you so much!